# iOS: detect incoming SMS

Tags: ios, sms

How does Fitbit app detect and show incoming SMS messages (including the text) on my watch for iOS? The only info I found it involves jailbreaking, but Fitbit (and all other watches companion apps) do the same without the need of jail break?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sort answer, it does not.
Your fit bit is a bluetooth device with the message extensions, this allows iOS to send notifications to you watch. 
It does not go thru the app.

Comment: Thank you very much. That explains it. Poor choice from iOS side. :(